# How to use case in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

**My Query is below**

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(controlId,1,1) = 'M' THEN (select fullname from master as controler 
where Regular.controlId = Master.MasterId)

WHEN SUBSTRING(controlId,1,1) = 'A' THEN (select fullname from Admin as controler 
where Regular.controlId = Master.AdminId)
END AS controler
FROM Regular
INNER JOIN Master ON Regular.ControlId = Master.MasterId 
INNER JOIN Admin ON Regular.ControlId = Admin.AdminId
Where (Regular.active=0)
```

**My tables**

[image]

**My Regular Data**

[image]

**My Master Table**

[image]

**My Admin table Data**

[image]

I want to get the full name from releated table for each row but using above code its not giving any result....

Comment: might want to try FullName instead of fullname

Comment: It would help to see sample Master/Admin data for those Regular records. Are you guaranteed to have a Master and Admin record for each Regular record? If not, do you really want to filter out Regular records that don't have corresponding records in both the Master and Admin tables, as your current query is doing?

Comment: Without seeing data sample for all tables, I am guessing it has something to do with your joins.

Comment: plus the normalization is the real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data seems poorly normalized, and there's not enough information in the question to know what's going on for sure, but I suspect that your joins are wrong, and you really need to use LEFT joins instead of INNER joins. Then you can use the COALESCE() function instead of CASE clauses:

```
SELECT r.*, COALESCE(m.FullName, a.FullName, r.FullName) FullName 
FROM Regular r
LEFT JOIN Master m ON r.ControlId = m.MasterId 
LEFT JOIN Admin a ON r.ControlId = a.AdminId
WHERE r.active=0
```

Comment: I got the result I'm new so request you to don't down vote me

Comment: you are not but someone else did twice

Answer (score 1):

I can't use `INNER JOIN`s

```
INNER JOIN Master ON Regular.ControlId = Master.MasterId 
INNER JOIN Admin ON Regular.ControlId = Admin.AdminId
```

the column `Regular.ControlId` can't exists in both tables `Master` and `Admin`

```
SELECT *, 
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(controlId,1,1) = 'M' THEN (select fullname from master as controler 
where Regular.controlId = Master.MasterId)

WHEN SUBSTRING(controlId,1,1) = 'A' THEN (select fullname from Admin as controler 
where Regular.controlId = Master.AdminId)
END AS controler
FROM Regular
Where (Regular.active=0)
```

Comment: agree, doesn't look like need of join here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe becouse the inner join. Try change to:

```
    SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(controlId,1,1) = 'M' THEN (select top 1 fullname from Master
    where Regular.controlId = Master.MasterId)

    WHEN SUBSTRING(controlId,1,1) = 'A' THEN (select top 1 fullname from Admin
    where Regular.controlId = Admin.AdminId)
    END AS controler
    FROM Regular
    Where (Regular.active=0)
```

Comment: Without inner join its give error...

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.